# Encontrar dados nao cadastrados no postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu tenho registros de campos que possuem campos com anos e meses tipo esse:

```
id  mes  ano
----------
1    1   2005
----------
2    2   2005
----------
3    4   2005
----------
4    5   2006
----------
```

Minha duvida é: É possivel encontrar no periodo de 2005 a 2015 todos os meses que não foram cadastrados?

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que sua tabela possua a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_ano_mes
(
    id bigserial,
    ano int,
    mes int,
    CONSTRAINT pk_ano_mes PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

Contendo os seguintes dados:

```
INSERT INTO tb_ano_mes ( id, mes, ano ) VALUES ( 1, 1, 2005 );
INSERT INTO tb_ano_mes ( id, mes, ano ) VALUES ( 2, 2, 2005 );
INSERT INTO tb_ano_mes ( id, mes, ano ) VALUES ( 3, 4, 2005 );
INSERT INTO tb_ano_mes ( id, mes, ano ) VALUES ( 4, 5, 2006 );
```

Seu problema pode ser solucionado com a função `generate_series()`, suportada desde a versão `9.1` do Postgres:

```
SELECT
     EXTRACT( MONTH FROM s)::int AS mes,
     EXTRACT( YEAR FROM s )::int AS ano
FROM
    generate_series( '01/01/2005', '31/12/2015', '1 month'::interval ) AS s
LEFT JOIN
    tb_ano_mes AS tbl ON ( EXTRACT(MONTH FROM s) = tbl.mes AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s) = tbl.ano )
WHERE
    tbl.id IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    ano,
    mes;
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score -1):

Uma pequena modificação na solução apenas, o padrão da data, que deve ser ***YYYY-MM-DD*** e para as versões mais atuais do PostgreSQL, a conversão do tipo deve ser explícita na maioria dos casos:

```
SELECT

     EXTRACT( MONTH FROM s)::int AS mes,
     EXTRACT( YEAR FROM s )::int AS ano
FROM
    generate_series( '2005-01-01'::date, '2015-12-31'::date, '1 month'::interval ) AS s

LEFT JOIN
    tb_ano_mes AS tbl ON ( EXTRACT(MONTH FROM s) = tbl.mes AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s) = tbl.ano )

WHERE
    tbl.id IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    ano,
    mes;
```

Comment: Isso não é uma regra, o formato de data depende de como a variável de ambiente 'DateStyle' está setada no cliente. Referência: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE